# mysql deadlock solution~

Tags: mysql

Mysql server seem to be in deadlock state because of transaction(race condition).

But, restarting Mysql server doesn't make faster or recover from locking state.
Web site is very very slow yet.

Basically yes, i have to change my web application queries first. 
But, is there any way to recover mysql server from locking state.

Deleting some table? or processing? or rollback?

Comment: Insufficient information for meaningful answer. Post: why do you think this is a deadlock? Do you mean you're getting deadlock errors from InnoDB? You say "web site is very slow", which implies that there is not a deadlock, just an efficiency problem. Consider asking Serverfault.com for help with diagnosis (then post a useful question on Stackoverflow if you like when you have got an accurate diagnosis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe killing the processes in mysql. You can go first

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

then
`mysql> kill 27`; (the corresponding processes)